# SharePlumRequestError: SharePlum HTTP Post Failed

Tags: python, sharepoint, python-requests, shared-libraries

**Error Screenshot:**

[image: Error Screenshot]

Hello Everyone,

I am trying to set up a connection to SharePoint list so I can read/write data to SharePoint. Below is the following code that I have ran to form a connection using SharePlum library. I am running the same exact code as the library suggests with my credentials and url but I get this error which I can't see to find online anywhere. I would really appreciate if you can help me fix this. Thanks.

```
ShareplumRequestError: Shareplum HTTP Post Failed : 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://abc.sharepoint.com/
```

```
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365

sharepointUsername = 'user@abc.com'
sharepointPassword = 'password!'
sharepointSite = 'https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/MySites/'
website = 'https://abc.sharepoint.com/'

authcookie = Office365(website, username=sharepointUsername, 
             password=sharepointPassword).GetCookies()
site = Site(sharepointSite, authcookie=authcookie)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to connect to SP online. Please specify **Version** parameter then try it again.

```
site = Site('https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/sbdev/subtest01',version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)
```

Full Code:
https://github.com/kongmengfei/sharedproject/blob/master/PythonConsole-uploadfileSPO/PythonApplication2/addDocLib.py

I have tested above demo in my SPO environment, you may have a look.

BR

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just one question; do I need to have access to my root url (https:/abc.sharepoint.com/) for this code to run? I have access to 'https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite' but not to the root url.

Comment: That error is coming from `Office365(website, username=sharepointUsername, password=sharepointPassword).GetCookies()` not the `Site(...)` one. @VatsalPatel how did you solve it?

Comment: nvm.. instead of `abc.sharepoint.com`, I'm using `abc-my.sharepoint.com`. I didn't have access to the former environment. thanks @Baker for linking your repo.. it was really helpful.

Comment: this worked for me i changes abc.sharepoint.com to abc-my.sharepoint.com @BalKrishnaJha worked for me adding version too is needed